# RCS using multiple files for checkin or checkout

Tags: rcs

I would like to know if there is any way to commit multiple files together in RCS. When i say together, it means that I have done my changes to multiple files but they are to be included in the same commit. I know that the checkin command is:

`ci -u filename`

Also, I know that for using a log message:

`ci -u -m 'message' filename.ext`

If someone could help me out, it will be great!

THNX

Comment: Are you being forced to use RCS?  Pretty much every VCS system out there is better than RCS (Git is my favorite).

Comment: @thirtythreeforty.             Yes...I m being forced to....my all time favourite is svn but cannot use it now

Comment: @thirtythreeforty RCS is file-based, and extremely lightweight. It's still a good choice for file-based revision control in certain use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pass Multiple Files as Arguments

RCS is file-based, so you can't really commit groups of files *as a group*. However, you can certainly pass multiple files to the `ci` command, and it will process each one in turn. You can even use the same commit message for all files checked in this way. For example, given both */tmp/foo* and */tmp/bar* are already in RCS:

```
$ $ ci -l -m'Interesting commit.' /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
/tmp/foo,v  <--  /tmp/foo
new revision: 1.2; previous revision: 1.1
done
/tmp/bar,v  <--  /tmp/bar
new revision: 1.2; previous revision: 1.1
done
```

Comment: thanks for that, I've already got the solution. The cygwin bash that I'm using has got `use` and `put` commands instead of `co` and `ci` respectively. But you are right saying that I can do multiple files, not files as a group. I will change the text in my original question.

Comment: I haven't checked that....I usually do 'use -e my_filename.ext" and `put -y "comments" my_filename.ext`

Comment: @hagubear: Try `type use` and `type put`. (That's if you use bash or something similar; if you use tcsh, try `where use` and `where put`). If you reply, don't forget the at-sign followed by my name; otherwise I won't be notified.

Answer (score 0):

Can you also apply a multi-line log message to multiple files by reading it from a file on the command line.

Let's say your multi-line log message is in a file named commit.msg.

ci -l -m"$(cat commit.msg)" /tmp/foo /tmp/bar

Note, the quotes on either side of the parens are required.